# SAS PRXPARSE usage to retrieve length of string matching pattern

Tags: regex, sas

I have to retrieve the X-Axis and Y-Axis pos from `ADDITIONAL_DETAILS` field which is more than 300 bytes in length.

Somewhere in this string, I am getting the location details as `RETLOCID=2312.4892` like that. 
I am trying to use `PERL REGEX` in `SAS`.

Problem: I am able to get the starting position into postn1 from call `prxsubstr(MATCH_PATTERN1, ADDITIONAL_DETAILS, postn1,length1)`; but the length is always returned as 8 even though it is more than that.

`TRANSACTION_ID = substrn(ADDITIONAL_DETAILS, postn1, length1)`; This is not giving me proper value when I am restricting length to 8. Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
DATA WORK.LOCATION;
  INFILE DATALINES; 
  INPUT ADDITIONAL_DETAILS $50.;
  datalines;
afdsf RFTXNID=121.5435 xx 
fdsg RFTXNID=7821.5487 xx fdsg
gfdgf
  ;
RUN;
data WORK.POSITION;
  set WORK.POSITION;
  if _N_ = 1 then do; 
    MATCH_PATTERN1 = PRXPARSE("/(RETLOCID=)/");
    MATCH_PATTERN2 = PRXPARSE("/([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})/");
  end;
  retain MATCH_PATTERN1 MATCH_PATTERN2;

  call prxsubstr(MATCH_PATTERN1, ADDITIONAL_DETAILS, postn1,length1);
  call prxsubstr(MATCH_PATTERN2, ADDITIONAL_DETAILS, postn2,length2);

  if postn1 > 0 and not missing(ADDITIONAL_DETAILS) then 
    TRANSACTION_ID = substrn(ADDITIONAL_DETAILS, postn1 + 8, length1);
RUN;

data work.POSITION;
  set work.POSITION;
  drop MATCH_PATTERN1 postn1 length1;
run;
```

I need to pull 121.5435 and 7821.5487

Comment: Can you provide some sample data as well?

Comment: Hi Robert, I added some datalines here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATA WORK.LOCATION;
INPUT ADDITIONAL_DETAILS $50.;
string=prxchange('s/[a-z=_]+//i',-1,ADDITIONAL_DETAILS);
datalines;
afdsf RFTXNID=121.5435 xx 
fdsg RFTXNID=7821.5487 xx fdsg
DISTR_QUOTE=66.92
gfdgf
;
run;
```

Or

```
DATA WORK.LOCATION;
INPUT ADDITIONAL_DETAILS $50.;
length string $20.;
if prxmatch('/\=/',ADDITIONAL_DETAILS)=0 then string='';
else string=prxchange('s/.*(?<=\=)([^a-z]+).*/$1/i',-1,ADDITIONAL_DETAILS);
datalines;
afdsf RFTXNID=121.5435 xx 
fdsg RFTXNID=7821.5487 xx fdsg
gfdgf
DISTR_QUOTE=66.92 
;
proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Another problem started :( When there are couple of other assignments in some rows. Like we have DISTR_QUOTE=66.92 in the same ADDITIONAL_DETAILS that is also getting populated in the string field .. When I give RFTXNID instead of a-z, I am getting additional characters into the field as well.

Comment: Your solution is working in the context only when there is one value that I need to pull. But if we have multiple it is failing. Could you please explain the parse logic as well? Do you know why the first one in my code did not work? Also why length1 is always getting populated as 8?

Comment: Basically using of regular expression was based on example, if you want to fix your problem, you must provide fully information in your example. So I edited the codes as your new example. In addition, your prxparse is wrong for MATCH_PATTERN1. Otherwise, it works.